# Consistent theory based on L and not(A->A) is a theorem

Tags: terminology, logic, first-order-logic, propositional-logic, theory

I am working on this problem in which I have a theory $T$ based on language $\mathcal{L}$ and the only information we have is that **T is consistent** and ***$\vdash \lnot(A \rightarrow A)$***. Given this information, how can I know if this theory is sound, complete and/or decidable?

My only guess is that I can say that $T$ is sound because since $T$ is consistent and we can derive ***$\lnot(A \rightarrow A)$*** from axioms and inference rules, ***$\lnot(A \rightarrow A)$*** is a theorem and because of that we can assume that $T$ is sound (because the premises and conclusions are true).

Am I correct? What else can I say about this theory?

Thank you!

Comment: Your problem statement makes no sense because in first-order classical logic $\lnot (A \to A)$ is false, and therefore it can only be a theorem in inconsistent theory. Please double check that you transcribed it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that we're working in the context of classical propositional logic.

The first thing to point out is that $\lnot(A \rightarrow A)$ leads to a contradiction: ($A \land \lnot A$). Since propositional logic itself is consistent, it is impossible to derive a contradiction, so $\vdash \lnot(A \rightarrow A)$ is impossible.

So perhaps your intention was $T \vdash \lnot(A \rightarrow A)$. This can only happen if $T$ is itself inconsistent.

Given that $T$ is inconsistent, $T$ is vacuously [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_theory) (since an inconsistent theory can prove any formula) and [decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)) (for the same reason). As for soundness, it's a property of the logical system, not any particular theory like $T$. Propositional logic is [sound](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2800/2017fa/lectures/lec38-sound.html).